# Open URL from bokeh, not using the taptool

Tags: bokeh

I am looking to open a URL from bokeh using OpenURL, but from within a callback for a button, not using taptool. The code below reproduces the issue I'm running into i.e. I can open new tabs when using taptool with OpenURL, but nothing happens when I use OpenURL in a button callback. 
(Much of the example is from the bokeh docs: http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.12.5/docs/user_guide/examples/interaction_open_url.html)

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, OpenURL, TapTool
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import column, widgetbox
from bokeh.io import curdoc

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
           tools="tap", title="Click the Dots")
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(
    x=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[2, 5, 8, 2, 7],
    color=["navy", "orange", "olive", "firebrick", "gold"]
    ))
p.circle('x', 'y', color='color', size=20, source=source)
url = "http://www.colors.commutercreative.com/@color/"
taptool = p.select(type=TapTool)
taptool.callback = OpenURL(url=url)

button = Button(label="Generate", button_type="success")
def button_callback():
    print('button callback')
    OpenURL(url="http://www.google.com")
button.on_click(button_callback)

doc = curdoc()
doc.add_root(column([p,widgetbox(button)]))
doc.title = "Hello World"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OpenURL` is a custom version of `CustomJS`, so it runs only in JavaScript. It's also a class and not a function - you can't just construct an object of class `OpenURL`, you also have to use its other methods to make it work.

With that being said, you cannot use it with `Button` since  `OpenURL` expects a data source to replace all the placeholders in the URL. And `Button` can't have a data source.

Instead, what you need is a regular `CustomJS`:

```py
b.js_on_click(CustomJS(args=dict(urls=['https://www.google.com',
                                       'https://stackoverflow.com/']),
                       code="urls.forEach(url => window.open(url))"))
```

Note that how the solution above will work depends on your browser. E.g. in my case Google Chrome was opening only the first URL, and I had to explicitly allow pop-ups for the generated web page before it started to also open the second URL.

And you don't need `bokeh serve` to make it work - it will work even on a static web page generated by a call to `save` or `show`.

Comment: Thank you. This isn't obvious from my example, but what I'm trying to do so parametrize window.open. I.e. I have a list of URLS that should be an argument to js_on_click, and clicking the button should launch all of them. Is that possible with js_on_click?

Comment: Sure, I've updated the answer. Make sure to read the note right under the code block.